# Installing wget on mac - unable to find .bashrc file

Tags: linux, macos, wget

I am trying to install WGET on my macbook.
I am using [this tutorial](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-install-wget-om-mac-os-x-mountain-lion-mavericks-snow-leopard/) to do so.

I came to the final step but it says:

> If you do not see output, edit `$HOME/.bash_profile` or `$HOME/.bashrc` and
>   add/edit/append PATH as follows: `export PATH=${PATH}:/usr/local/bin`

Where can I find `$HOME/.bash_profile` ? Can someone give me the exact path to `$HOME/.bash_profile` ?

When I type `$HOME/.bashrc` I get the following output.

```
-bash: /Users/Clara/.bashrc: No such file or directory
```

Comment: Err, that is the full path!

Comment: I have updated my code. Please have a look

Comment: Start `Textedit` and navigate to your Home directory and open `.bash_profile`. If it doesn't exist, just enter "PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin` and save it as `.bash_profile`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$HOME` refers to your home directory, which seems to be `/Users/Clara` in your case.
If the files `.bashrc` or `.bash_profile` do not yet exist, you can just create them with a simple text editor.

Comment: you mean like `vi .bash_profile` ? Should i include the `.` (dot) as well.